# String manipulation when given an integer parameter Python

Tags: python, string, svg

I am manipulating an SVG file.
I have this string as a style

```
'.cls-1{fill:#755841;}.cls-2{fill:#f7c394;}.cls-3{fill:#9b7657;}.cls- 
4{fill:#7f6145;}.cls-5{fill:#ffc9a1;}.cls-6{fill:#ffcd98;}.cls- 
7{fill:#3d0c0c;}.cls-8{fill:#fff;}.cls-9{fill:#313cc4;}'
```

I want to create a function that receives an input say 14 and changes this string to start at a number that is continuing from the input. For example here classes will start from 14 + 1 = 15 and so on:

```
'.cls-15{fill:#755841;}.cls-16{fill:#f7c394;}.cls-17{fill:#9b7657;}.cls- 
18{fill:#7f6145;}.cls-19{fill:#ffc9a1;}.cls-20{fill:#ffcd98;}.cls- 
21{fill:#3d0c0c;}.cls-22{fill:#fff;}.cls-23{fill:#313cc4;}'
```

Not really sure what will be the best approach. Is it regex?

Comment: Split then replace and increments

Comment: Using a parser that someone else has already written an debugged and verified is really the way to go.   Don't re-invent the wheel.  See my cssutils answer below.

Comment: Thank you. I did end up stuck and asked a follow up question if you wish to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660221/string-manipulation-when-given-an-integer-parameter-python?noredirect=1#comment88330575_50660221

Comment: Where is the follow up question?   The link is for this post.

Comment: Whoops. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663649/changing-a-path-class-name-in-svg-python/50673323#50673323

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the string is actually CSS code.  How about parsing it with a python CSS parser and then access the resulting objects pragmatically?

Using **cssutils**: [link](https://pypi.org/project/cssutils/)

```
import cssutils

css = '.cls-1{fill:#755841;}.cls-2{fill:#f7c394;}.cls-3{fill:#9b7657;}.cls-4{fill:#7f6145;}.cls-5{fill:#ffc9a1;}.cls-6{fill:#ffcd98;}.cls-7{fill:#3d0c0c;}.cls-8{fill:#fff;}.cls-9{fill:#313cc4;}'

sheet = cssutils.parseString(css)

for rule in sheet:
    text = rule.selectorText.split('-')
    name,num = text
    num = int(num)
    num += 10

    rule.selectorText = name + '-' + str(num)        

print sheet.cssText.translate(None, ' \n\t\r')
```

output:

```
.cls-11{fill:#755841}.cls-12{fill:#f7c394}.cls-13{fill:#9b7657}.cls-14{fill:#7f6145}.cls-15{fill:#ffc9a1}.cls-16{fill:#ffcd98}.cls-17{fill:#3d0c0c}.cls-18{fill:#fff}.cls-19{fill:#313cc4}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following ways:

**Include access to the outer scope:**

```
import re

start_point = 5

input_value = """.cls-1{fill:#755841;}.cls-2{fill:#f7c394;}.cls-3{fill:#9b7657;}.cls-4{fill:#7f6145;}.cls-5{fill:#ffc9a1;}.cls-6{fill:#ffcd98;}.cls-7{fill:#3d0c0c;}.cls-8{fill:#fff;}.cls-9{fill:#313cc4;}"""


def callback(match):
    global start_point
    start_point += 1

    return '{key}{value}'.format(
        key=match.group(1),
        value=start_point
    )


result = re.sub('(cls-)([0-9]+)', callback, input_value)

print(result)
```

**Without access to the outer scope:**

```
import re

from functools import partial

start_point = 5

input_value = """.cls-1{fill:#755841;}.cls-2{fill:#f7c394;}.cls-3{fill:#9b7657;}.cls-4{fill:#7f6145;}.cls-5{fill:#ffc9a1;}.cls-6{fill:#ffcd98;}.cls-7{fill:#3d0c0c;}.cls-8{fill:#fff;}.cls-9{fill:#313cc4;}"""


def callback(point, match):
    point[0] += 1

    return '{key}{value}'.format(
        key=match.group(1),
        value=point[0]
    )


func = partial(callback, [start_point])
result = re.sub('(cls-)([0-9]+)', func, input_value)

print(result)
```

**Result:**

- **Input:** .cls-1{fill:#755841;}.cls-2{fill:#f7c394;}.cls-3{fill:#9b7657;}.cls-4{fill:#7f6145;}.cls-5{fill:#ffc9a1;}.cls-6{fill:#ffcd98;}.cls-7{fill:#3d0c0c;}.cls-8{fill:#fff;}.cls-9{fill:#313cc4;}
- **Start point:** 5
- **Output:** .cls-6{fill:#755841;}.cls-7{fill:#f7c394;}.cls-8{fill:#9b7657;}.cls-9{fill:#7f6145;}.cls-10{fill:#ffc9a1;}.cls-11{fill:#ffcd98;}.cls-12{fill:#3d0c0c;}.cls-13{fill:#fff;}.cls-14{fill:#313cc4;}

Comment: Thank you, seems to work. I ended up asking a follow up question. If you are intrested in helping the url is: Thanks you. Seems to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660221/string-manipulation-when-given-an-integer-parameter-python?noredirect=1#comment88330575_50660221

Answer (score 2):

you can use the function `sub` of `re`:

```
import re
def increment_value_in_string (s, inc_value):
    return re.sub('(?<=\.cls-)\d*',lambda m: str(inc_value+int(m.group(0))),s)

string = '.cls-1{fill:#755841;} ... '
increment_value = 14
new_string = increment_value_in_string(string, increment_value)
```

you look for any digit `\d*` after the substring `.cls-` and you replace using the function `lambda m: str(inc_value+int(m.group(0)))` where m.group(0) is the string containing the digits found

Comment: Thank you. I ended up asking a follow up question. If you are intrested in helping the url is: Thanks you. Seems to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660221/string-manipulation-when-given-an-integer-parameter-python?noredirect=1#comment88330575_50660221